# Python fractional knapsack

Tags: python, knapsack-problem

Question: 
The goal of this code problem is to implement an algorithm for the fractional knapsack problem

Input: 
The first line of the input contains the number  of items and the capacity  of a knapsack.The next  lines define the values and weights of the items. The -th line contain integers  and  which is the value and the weight of -th item, respectively.

Output:
Output the maximal value of fractions of items that fit into the knapsack. The absolute value of the difference between the answer of your program and the optimal value should be at most 0.001.

Below is my answer:

```
import sys

def get_optimal_value(capacity, weights, values):

    unit_value = [a/b for a,b in zip(values,weights)]
    unit_value = sorted(unit_value, key=int, reverse=True)
    m = len(unit_value)

    if capacity == 0: return []
    for i in range(0,m):
        if weights[i] > capacity: return unit_value[i]*capacity
        if weights[i] <= capacity: return values[i] + get_optimal_value(capacity-weights[i], weights, values)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = [int(x) for x in input("").split()]
    n, capacity = data[0:2]
    values = data[2:(2 * n + 2):2]
    weights = data[3:(2 * n + 2):2]
    opt_value = get_optimal_value(capacity, weights, values)
    print("{:.10f}".format(opt_value))
```

However, when I run the case as

```
n = 3 , capacity = 50,
1st item: 60 20
2nd item: 100 50
3rd item: 120 30
```

The output is 160 not as 180 which is the correct answer.

Comment: You sort the unit_values, but don't seem to sort weights and values? Also, that second if in the for loop is redundant.

Comment: Thanks for your solution! I got it